# Google authentication using azure services

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure-mobile-services, google-authentication

I authenticate **Google account** using **azure services** in visual studio (c#).

I got **access token** from Google account.

How can I fetch user information from that access token?

my server side code

```
var user = User as ServiceUser;
var identities = await user.GetIdentitiesAsync();
var googleCredential = identities[0] as Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Service.Security.GoogleCredentials;
var accessToken = googleCredential.AccessToken;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to talk directly to the Google API with the customer token to get information about that user.

Here is a link to a blog post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2012/10/25/getting-user-information-on-azure-mobile-services.aspx

Here is a link to the Google API: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#windows-phone-81

Here is an example with a Node.js Backend:

```
function insert(item, user, request) {
    item.UserName = "<unknown>"; // default
    user.getIdentities({
        success: function (identities) {
            var req = require('request');
            if (identities.google) {
                var googleAccessToken = identities.google.accessToken;
                var url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo?access_token=' + googleAccessToken;
                req(url, function (err, resp, body) {
                    if (err || resp.statusCode !== 200) {
                        console.error('Error sending data to Google API: ', err);
                        request.respond(statusCodes.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, body);
                    } else {
                        try {
                            var userData = JSON.parse(body);
                            item.UserName = userData.name;
                            request.execute();
                        } catch (ex) {
                            console.error('Error parsing response from Google API: ', ex);
                            request.respond(statusCodes.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, ex);
                        }
                    }
                });
            } else {
                // Insert with default user name
                request.execute();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Is there any other way to get user information form access token from using server side controller??